# jekyll blog on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

I'm trying to setup a jekyll blog on heroku. This is my dir structure

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── _layouts
│   └── default.html
├── _posts
├── _site
│   ├── Gemfile
│   ├── Gemfile.lock
│   ├── config.ru
│   └── index.html
├── config.ru
└── index.html
```

My Gemfile has

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem 'jekyll'
```

and only other file with anything in it is `index.html` with

```
Hello world!
```

If I run `jekyll --server` it runs fine locally. But if I `git push heroku master` (after checking everything in) I get this error in my heroku logs

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I get my jekyll blog to work on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with phsr's answer. Static websites might be better served using amazon CDN or something similar. However to answer your question:

- Check your static files into your git repo. E.g. into a directory like "public".
- Set up a config.ru file to use a middleware like [rack-static-if-present](https://github.com/samsm/rack-static-if-present) and point it towards the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll generates static HTML files, so there is no need to use Heroku.  It would be a better idea to host it on S3. See [this Amazon blog post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html) on hosting a static site on S3.  With the AWS Free tier, your site would be completely free for the first year (as long as it's under 5 GB in size), and would cost pennies a month after that

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems getting a jekyll blog running on Heroku, but managed it in the end.

If this is still relevant, you can see the full code here on github: https://github.com/ramijames/Blueverve_public

You can clone and push to a heroku app and fiddle with the actual setup there.